# How to get ids from ormlite SaveAll() call

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using ORMLite to save a number of objects, similar to:

```
var graphs = Builder<UserGraph>.CreateListOfSize(10)
            .And(x => x.UserId = User.Id)
            .Build();

Db.SaveAll(graphs);
```

Is there a way to have the id property for each object get set automatically.  If not, is there a way to get the ids for all of the inserted objects?

Comment: Can you add the definition for the `UserGraph` object? When you say `get the ids for all of the inserted objects?` do you mean after the `SaveAll` call?

Comment: Your POCO should have the id set on the primary key mapped property.

Comment: You can also get the ID of the last inserted object via `Db.LastInsertId()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an AutoIncrement attribute to your Id property :

```
[AutoIncrement]
public int UserId{ get; set; }
```